# -1 how to print the data in thermal printer in regional languages like Hindi, java string in Hindi by thermal printer?

Tags: java, android

How to print the data in thermal printer in regional languages like Hindi, Java string in Hindi by thermal printer?

Eg `String s1 = "तुम कैसे हो";` prints garbage values.

Comment: i am using pos printer like hoin,domipos

Comment: Thermal printer?

Comment: Probably depends on the printer and what kind of character sets it supports(?)